# Ошибка при обновление с Laravel 5.0 до 5.1

Tags: laravel

При обновлении возникла такая ошибка

> Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider' not found in
>   /var/www/mans.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
>   on line 150

Если в `config/app.php` комментирую то все норм что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос установкой по соседству Laravel 5.1 и переносом скриптов, никак не лечится по другому можно закрывать вопрос